# Django query annotate after filter doesn't work correctly

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-annotate

I have two models that are related using a m2m relationship through an intermediate model:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                          through="Join", blank=True,
                                          related_name="chats")


class Join(models.Model):
    """Intermediate model for relations between a user and a chat."""

    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name="joins")
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=("user", "chat"),
                name="user_join_once_constraint"
            )
        ]
```

When I do this:

```
chats = Chat.objects.annotate(Count("participants")).filter(participants=user)
chats.get(pk=11).participants__count
```

It will return 2; which is correct. But when I do this:

```
chats = Chat.objects.filter(participants=user).annotate(Count("participants"))
chats.get(pk=11).participants__count
```

It will return 1.

My understanding is that the first one is counting the number of relations for each `chat` object while the second one is counting how many times the `user` is related to each `chat` object.

What I want is to annotate a pre-evaluated queryset with number of relationships for each object.

What's wrong? what am I doing wrong? I need to annotate a filtered queryset.

---

SQL:

First one (annotate first):

```
SELECT "msgr_chat"."id", "msgr_chat"."lat", COUNT("msgr_join"."user_id") AS "participants__count" FROM "msgr_chat" LEFT OUTER JOIN "msgr_join" ON ("msgr_chat"."id" = "msgr_join"."chat_id") INNER JOIN "msgr_join" T4 ON ("msgr_chat"."id" = T4."chat_id") WHERE T4."user_id" = 7 GROUP BY "msgr_chat"."id"
```

Second one (filter first):

```
SELECT "msgr_chat"."id", "msgr_chat"."lat", COUNT("msgr_join"."user_id") AS "participants__count" FROM "msgr_chat" INNER JOIN "msgr_join" ON ("msgr_chat"."id" = "msgr_join"."chat_id") WHERE "msgr_join"."user_id" = 7 GROUP BY "msgr_chat"."id"
```

Comment: Instead of annotate try using aggregate like filter(participants=user).aggregate(Count("participants"))

Comment: @SmitParmar But I need to further filter the queryset to find for example, objects that have 2 participants. And what you are suggesting returned `{'participants__count': 4}`.

Comment: Can you wrtie sql query of both orms by just appending .query at the end ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I added them to my question.

Comment: Try to understand both the queries by creating venn diagram you will get your query resolved.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I'm not really familiar with sql. you don't know how can I fix this in Django? In my edit to the question I explained what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: share your models as well ..!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this problem in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses).

Apparently:

> filter() and annotate() are not commutative operations.

I have to annotate all of the objects first, and then use filter on it; to almost get what I want.

But I still don't know what should I do if I want to annotate a queryset that is not directly from the model's manager.